# AttributeError while running python multiprocessing

Tags: pycharm, multiprocessing, python-3.8

I am using the following code:

```
import sys, os, pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myFunc(inp):
    try:
        simDate, ii = inp['simDate'], inp['ii']
        print(ii)
    except:
        print('error at ', ii)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    simDate = '2021-07-14'
    stDt, enDt = '2021-08-01', '2022-05-31'
    days = pd.date_range(stDt, enDt).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    inpData = [{'simDate':simDate, 'ii':ii} for ii in days]
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(myFunc, inpData)
```

The above gives error:

```
return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'myFunc' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I have no clue what is going on here. This has started happening after I updated PyCharm. Is this related to PyCharm?

Comment: Looks like a PyCharm bug indeed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50020

Comment: The new update is pretty messed up, lot of other issues are there like it gets stuck during debugging and I cant kill it using task manager since the exe is not showing up there.